# Amazon Mobile Analytics for Websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, google-analytics, tracking, amazon-mobile-analytics

I know, it's called Amazon **Mobile** Analytics but is there a way of tracking website usage data including revenue, referrals etc via the JavaScript SDK, too? A hosted service that provides such detailed export functionality like this AWS service would we super cool for later aggregations and evaluations via Redshift.
And the pricing model is also very interesting compared to services like Mixpanel and co.

Does anyone have experiences?

Comment: I suspect it's doable. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-mobile-analytics-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some of the default KPIs displayed in the Amazon Mobile Analytics console are certainly focused towards mobile apps, there is nothing that makes it exclusively mobile.

Between the [REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/server-reference.html) and the [JS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-mobile-analytics-js), there is certainly nothing stopping from Server Side or Web Analytics.

A quick look through the [forums](http://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=174&start=0) shows a number of people discussing custom SDKs (Adobe Air) and submission from websites, AWS Lambda Functions, and Servers.

Comment: Hi thanks @Cheruvian . I totally agree. There shouldn't be anything in the way. Also good idea to check their forums :P